# .sln file disappears and build hangs

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Had to relocated our SVN repository, I edited the ccNet.config removed our state files and the old build directories. My build will start and pulls down the project for SVN but right after getting my project from SVN the build hangs and the .sln file gets deleted. Any Ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify (this was flagged for attention) .sln refers to a Visual Studio *solution* file, if I remember correctly.  This is separate from a .svn file, so the file extensions in the title and body are correct.

Answer (score 0):

From the question it is not really clear what you mean by build. I understood it is the complete CruiseControl build process [Event -> Checkout/Update -> Compilation -> Tests], not the compilation.

I would check these in order:

1. Did you relocate the local copies used by CruiseControl.NET?
2. Check the SVN URL path associated with the working copy, and its revision, did it really update to what you expect?
3. Check the credentials, do you provide them in the CC config or do you rely on the SVN client credential cache. This might have to be updated.
4. Activate Debugging in the CCnet config and have a deeper look at the log file.

What sounds strange is why the .sln file would be deleted, was it really in the repository or only created in the past because you opened a project file? A reason could be an uncommitted SVN delete made by mistake. A revert on the local copy can help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Jdehaan, your answer was very helpful. We had a couple projects on the build server pointed to the old repository that needed to be relocated.

Comment: SO uses comments rather than new answers to comment on someone else's response =)